# Editing header of a file in bash

Tags: awk, sed, header, edit

I have a file containing the following header.

```
LESlike5.fasta_LESlike5|6543350|2181116|74|Aca1|1.9e-49|167.1|567531|567602|1|1|1702592|1702805|1697592|1707805
```

I can't annotated the file in our in-house prokka due to long header.So, I want the header like following:

```
LESlike5.fasta_1702592_1702805_1697592_1707805
```

I understand sed command might work, but I can't remove the special character '|' by using sed. I tried `sed 's/|/'` to remove but i didn't work. How can I edit the header?

Comment: Solved by using the following  sed -E 's/[|]/\t/g' | cut -f1,14,15 | sed -E 's/\t/_/g'

Comment: Remove all `|`: `s/|//g`. Replace all `|` with `_`: `s/|/_/g`

Answer (score 2):

With awk: Use `|` and `_` as input field separator (`FS`) and `_` as output field separator (`OFS`) and print first (`$1`) and last four columns. `$NF` contains last column.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[|_]"; OFS="_"} {print $1,$(NF-3),$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' file
```

Output:

```
LESlike5.fasta_1702592_1702805_1697592_1707805
```

Comment: Thanks. The following also work for me : sed -E 's/[|]/\t/g' | cut -f1,14,15 | sed -E 's/\t/_/g'

Comment: @user266095 think about what your doing there - if you weren't adding the `-E`s then you wouldn't need to escape the `|`, and if you used `_` as the delimiter for `cut` then you wouldn't need 2 seds, you could just use 1, and in fact you don't even need `sed` you could just use `tr '|' '_' < file | cut -d_ -f1,14,15`.